# Notify Icon change span text on asp.net masterpage

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a master page with a notify Icon that returns a number from an sql query count.  I'm not able to change the text on page load it just stays at "7".  How do I go about changing that text on pageload?  Below is my code

```
 <li>
<table border="0" align="left" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="7" 
style="margin-top:20px;" ><tr>
 <td class="auto-style1">

 <div id="noti_Container">
 <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
 NavigateUrl="../manage2.aspx"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i>
</asp:HyperLink>
<div class="noti_bubble"><asp:Label ID="Notifyme" runat="server"  Text="7"/> 
</asp:Label> </div>
</div>
</td>
<td class="auto-style1">
</li>
```

Here is the Code Behind:

```
       SqlConnection CON = new SqlConnection(Testdb);
            {
                CON.Open();
                string ShiftTime = "SELECT count(discard) as alert FROM [Rejected].[dbo].[InQuestion] where discard = '0'";
                SqlCommand ShiftTimecalculate = new SqlCommand(ShiftTime, CON);
                SqlDataReader readershifttime = 
                ShiftTimecalculate.ExecuteReader();
                readershifttime.Read();
                if(readershifttime.hasrows)

      {
      Label noti_bubble = noti_Container.FindControl("Notifyme") as Label;
      Notifyme.innertext = readershifttime["alert"].ToString();
      readershifttime.Close();
      }
```

Comment: Do you have compile errors which you haven't mentioned? `Label noti_bubble = noti_Container.FindControl("Notifyme") as Label;` seems to be redundant. You don't use it for anything, and I doubt it would work anyway if you did, those objects don't exist server-side. And so far as I can see an asp:Label doesn't have an "innertext" property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label(v=vs.110).aspx.  Try using "Text" instead: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.text(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few modifications in your code:

1. If you want to use 'noti_container' in the code then use 'runat' attribute in order to resolve the error.
2. Notifyme.innertext: 'innertext' is not the property of a asp:Label. User 'Text' property
3. Avoid the line of code and unnecessary object creation

So, your code will be like below in the master page:

```
    <li>
<table border="0" align="left" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="7"
       style="margin-top:20px;">
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style1">

            <div id="noti_Container" runat="server">
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server"
                               NavigateUrl="../manage2.aspx">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i>
                </asp:HyperLink>
                <div class="noti_bubble">
                    <asp:Label ID="Notifyme" runat="server" Text="7" />

                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style1">
</li>
```

And Code behind:

```
           SqlConnection CON = new SqlConnection(Testdb);
        {
            CON.Open();
            string ShiftTime = "SELECT count(discard) as alert FROM [Rejected].[dbo].[InQuestion] where discard = '0'";
            SqlCommand ShiftTimecalculate = new SqlCommand(ShiftTime, CON);
            SqlDataReader readershifttime =
            ShiftTimecalculate.ExecuteReader();
            readershifttime.Read();
            if (readershifttime.hasrows)

            {
                Notifyme.Text = readershifttime["alert"].ToString();
                readershifttime.Close();
            }
        }
```

I hope this helps.